# Double integral proving that a function is a probability density

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

If

$$g(x,y)=f(x+y)/(x+y)$$

for $x,y>0$ and

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(z) \, dz = 1$$

How do you show that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x+y)}{x+y} dx \, dy = 1$$

as well?

Comment: Quite peculiar: you define $g(x,y)$ and leave it there :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: That may be due in part to my editing.

Answer (score 3):

Sub $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$ with Jacobian $J=1/2$:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, \int_0^{\infty} dy \frac{f(x+y)}{x+y} = \frac12 \int_0^{\infty} du \int_{-u}^u dv \frac{f(u)}{u} = \int_0^{\infty} du \, f(u) = 1$$